# Make Webview occupy whole dialog window in Android

Tags: android, webview, android-dialogfragment, android-fullscreen

I have a dialog fragment in my application which I want to occupy the whole screen. Since I need my fragment to extend my custom layout and want to add views to this dialog dynamically I wrote the code as below :-

**my_dialog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.MyDialogRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/dialogRootLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
     >

</com.example.MyDialogRelativeLayout>
```

Now inside my dialog java class I wrote :-

**MyDialogFragment.java**

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    WebView webView;
    MyDialogRelativeLayout dialogLayout;
    String url;



    public MyDialogFragment(String url)
    {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_custom_dialog,container, false);


        dialogLayout = (MyDialogRelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dialogRootLayout);

        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int height = dm.heightPixels;
        int width = dm.widthPixels;
        Log.d("Dialog","Height = "+height+" Widht = "+width);
        getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(width-50,height);


        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsWeb = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);
        final WebView wv = new WebView(getActivity());
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.loadUrl(url);

        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
                {
                    wv.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/nointernet.html");
                }
            });
        dialogLayout.addView(wv,paramsWeb);


        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

        Button closeButton = new Button(getActivity());
        closeButton.setText("Close");
        closeButton.setBackground(null);
        dialogLayout.addView(closeButton,params);


        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                getDialog().dismiss();

            }
        });


    }



    public class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{



        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }


    }
```

My problem is that, the webview doesnot occupy the whole window of the dialog which is drawn to the screen. There is a black layer/area on top of the dialog and the webview is below it.

**How to get rid of the top black portion and make the webview fill the whole dialog ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following for setting the height and width inside your fragment class: `getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(width, height);`

For removing the black part(title) use the following in your fragment class: `getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`